# How to find out from where is a Python script called?

Tags: python, bash, shell

I need to test whether several .py scripts (all part of a much bigger program) work after updating python. The only thing I have is their path. Is there any intelligent way how to find out from which other scripts are these called? Brute-forece grepping wasn't as good aas I expected.

Comment: Really, the only correct way is to have comprehensive test coverage and run your program through the test suite after changing python versions.

Comment: that is exactly what I did, I picked and ran all the test suites for the apps that may be using the given scripts, but I'd like to go a bit further.

Comment: ```os.walk``` the paths, read the .py files, search for ```import``` AND module_name(s) on the same line, accumulate the results.

Comment: If the tests pass, and you have good test coverage, then this is far enough in my opinion.  To go further, you might be interested to checkout snakefood http://furius.ca/snakefood/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I combined two things:

- ran automated tests with the old and new version of pythona nd compared results
- used snakefood to track the dependencies and ran the parent scripts

Thanks for the os.walk and os.getppid suggestion, however, I didn't want to write/use any additional code.

Answer (score 1):

Use `os.getppid()` to get the parent PID from the process, and then you can grep for it or similar.

For example:

```
import os
import subprocess

ppid = os.getppid()
output = subprocess.check_output(['ps', str(ppid)])

print 'Some info about my parent process (%d):' % ppid
print output.strip().split('\n')[-1]
```